# android : parsing XML and insert to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Assume that I have file XML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<P>
    <Content>
        <id>1016576</id>
        <date>20.08.2012</date>
        <placeOfBirth>KUALA LUMPUR</placeOfBirth>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <id>1016620</id>
        <date>20.08.2012</date>
        <placeOfBirth>SINGAPORE</placeOfBirth>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <id>1020907</id>
        <date>20.08.2012</date>
        <placeOfBirth>SINGAPORE</placeOfBirth>
    </Content>
</P>
```

I want to parse all the text and insert into database table which have _id, date and placeOfBirth column. I've tried this :

```
    Activity activity1 = this;
    String str="";
    Resources res = activity1.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xmlPharser = res.getXml(R.xml.fileXML);
    String id,date,pob;
//database
        final databaseHelper myDbHelper = new databaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper.open();
//insert into table while parsing xml
        try {
            xmlPharser.next();
            int eventType = xmlPharser.getEventType();
            String event = ""+eventType;
            Log.d("Event", event);
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG )
            {
               if( xmlPharser.getName() == "id")
               {
                    id=xmlPharser.getText();
               }
               else if ( xmlPharser.getName() == "date" )
               {
                    date = xmlPharser.getText();
               }
               else if ( xmlPharser.getName() == "placeOfBirth" )
               {
                    pob = xmlPharser.getText();
               }
               myDbHelper.insertData(id,date,pob);
               myDbHelper.close();
            }
            eventType = xmlPharser.next();
        }
  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

It doesn't get any error LogCat display, but it dosen't test the condition at each START_TAG.

How can I resolve this problem... 
All answer would be appreciated..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing XML can get really nasty if you're not careful, specially with this parsers; you could try some other with simpler APIs or clearer ways of going through the hierarchy (ie. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)). You should also take a look at the examples at the Android developer's site, it's really straight forward ([Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)).

All that been said, I fixed it for you. This should work (at least it does for me). Be careful though, it doesn't have any error checking on malformed XML or database stuff.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.filexml);

        final databaseHelper myDbHelper = null;

        try {
            myDbHelper = new databaseHelper(this);
            myDbHelper.open();
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("Content")) {
                    String id = null, date = null, pob = null;
                    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equals("id")) {
                            id = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("date")) {
                            date = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("placeOfBirth")) {
                            pob = readText(parser);
                        }
                    }
                    myDbHelper.insertData(id,date,pob);
                }
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (myDbHelper != null) {
                myDbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

One more comment, change the xml file name to lowercase ;)

Comment: thanks you so much for your reply...it works wells but why it insert only 3 or 4 rows each time i run the app. It's not insert all the data until it reach the end of xml file.

Comment: As I said I'm not checking for well-formedness on the XML, so the problem might be there. This code assumes that there's going to be a P tag, and then inside several Content tags and inside of those the id, date and placeOfBirth; make sure that you have all the tags (opening and closing), and all the elements are correctly nested. And then if you need it you can add some code to fix errors while parsing (or at least show them to you so you know what's going on). I can only work with what you gave us, and for that small test scenario it's working...

Comment: Thanks again, I've just found that, my xml is not well-form....i'll try your instruction ....thanks you so much for your kindness

Comment: @ZhDev I am trying to achieve that but I don't know how to start, I have parsed a xml but to insert in SQLite db I don't know how to do that ?
Because I want to add data there delete but some data I have declared manually and other data will give the user ?
Can we discuss for this ?